# Is it possible to get the 6.0.8 version as the 6.5.0 version doesn't seem to be reliable?

Tags: help

When I click on a link in an onion site, more times than not it says can't connect.  When I press retry, it works.  Another problem is downloading an archive.  The download starts and then fails after a minute or so.  It makes no difference what the site is - all downloads fail. Tor 6.0.8 worked just fine.

(Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to get the 6.0.8 version*

Yes, you can download it in https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/6.0.8/ Onion link for onion lovers: yjuwkcxlgo7f7o6s.onion/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/6.0.8/

Comment: However, if you choose to downgrade you will be exposing yourself to being hacked so it's not something you should ever do.